# Tricky mod_rewrite challenge

Tags: apache, redirects, url, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I list about 9,000 records on my little site. At the moment I'm showing them with a dynamic page, like

```
http://domain.com/records.php?id=019031
```

But I'd like to start using meaningful URLs like this one on Amazon

```
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Library-Mythology-Oxford-Worlds-Classics/dp/0199536325
```

where the title string on the root level gets ignored and requests are redirected to the records.php page, which accepts the ID as usual.

Does anybody know how I could achieve that with mod_rewrite? I'm wondering how I'd deal with requests to my other root-level pages, like `http://domain.com/contact.php`, that I don't want to redirect to the records page.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` supports [regular expressions](http://regular-expressions.info/), so you'll probably end up using a regular expression that matches `/[title-string]/[id]` (such as `^/[\w-]*/(\d+)$`), and redirect that ignoring the title string. Unfortunately I don't have enough `mod_rewrite` experience to tell you the syntax off the top of my head!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your root's .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(\d+)$ records.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

`http://example.com/foo-bar/42` will be rewritten to `http://example.com/records.php?id=42`

It wont affect URLs like `contact.php`, since it does not match `^[^/]+/(\d+)$`